# PGP encrypt an input file in Python given a public key

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, pgp, openpgp

Thanks in advance!

I am new to Python.

I want to PGP encrypt a file named "input.csv" using a downloaded "pgp_keys.asc" file.

Here is my attempt:

```
def encrypt(key, src):

    import requests
    r = requests.get(key)

    with open("/home/zzz/.gnupg/pgp_keys.asc",'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)
        f.close()

    import gnupg
    gpg=gnupg.GPG(homedir='/home/zzz/.gnupg/')
    f = open(src,'rb')
    status = gpg.encrypt(f)

    print(status.ok)
    print(status.status)
    print(status.stderr)
```

But code fails with

False
None
gpg: Sorry, no terminal at all requested - can't get input

My use case is given an input file and public key, encrypt that file.

Comment: What line gives you that error?

Comment: @Alderven This line prints that error                                         print(status.stderr)